# Compatibility Issue with undetected_chromedriver.v2 and Chrome Version 120.00

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, undetected-chromedriver

I am currently working on a Selenium project that involves using an undetected browser system. However, I am encountering compatibility issues between my Chrome browser version (120.00) and the undetected_chromedriver.v2 library, which requires driver version 114.00.

**Issue:**

- **Chrome Version:** 120.00
- **Required Chromedriver Version by undetected_chromedriver.v2:** 114.00

**Question:**

1. **How can I resolve this compatibility issue between my Chrome version (120.00) and the required Chromedriver version (114.00) by undetected_chromedriver.v2?**
2. **Is there a way to specify a different Chromedriver version with undetected_chromedriver.v2?**
3. **Does anyone have experience working with undetected browsers and can provide insights on handling compatibility issues?**

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import random
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import time

chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", \["enable-automation"\])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('headless', False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('use_subprocess', True)

# Create a Chrome object using the ChromeOptions

driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'path\\to\\chromedriver.exe')```
````